# UITableView resetting UITableViewCell after reloading

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

For start how I've created expandable cell with UIPicker. Just in case that would be relevant to issue.

It's created in UITableView by this code

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var identifyer = ""
    switch(indexPath.row){
  //other cells
    case 1:
        //Kategoria
        identifyer = "category"
        categoryCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifyer) as? CategoryTableViewCell
        categoryCell.pickerView.delegate = self
        categoryCell.pickerView.dataSource = self
        return categoryCell
  //other cells
}
```

Then I have to recognize if it's touched

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (indexPath.row == 1){
        isCategoryCellSelected = true
        tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([categoryIndexPath()], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    }
}
```

That's how I replace text in `UILabel`

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    categoryCell.categoryNameLabel.text = categories[row]
}
```

And finaly when tableView refresh cell

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    switch(indexPath.row){
    case 1:
        if (isCategoryCellSelected){
            return CategoryTableViewCell.expandedHeight
        } else {
            return CategoryTableViewCell.defaultHeight
        }
     //other heights
    }
}
```

Defalut cell looks

[image: [defalut]]

Expanded cell looks

[image: [expanded]]

**ISSUE**

So when I choose item in picker then label above should have change it text and that is happening. However, when this cell shrink to default height then replace effect is gone. I have to scroll down and up to see that only then I can see changed text in label.

I assume that UITableView cache this cell and when cell is reloading then it takes this cached version. I'm only guessing. Is it how I think? How I can change this unwanted action?

### **SOLUTION**

As @the_critic pointout my approche to save cells in vars was completly wrong. In same time recreating categoryCell every time I pick row wasn't the correct way to do it. I end up with his way of creating cell but with mine way of setting value to cell.

So it looks like this what's is chagned:

**creating cell**

categoryIdentifier is `private let String`

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: UITableViewCell
    switch(indexPath.row){
// other cells
   case 1:
        //Kategoria
        print("recreate, selected category \(selectedCategory)")
        let categoryCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(categoryIdentifier) as! CategoryTableViewCell
        categoryCell.pickerView.delegate = self
        categoryCell.pickerView.dataSource = self
        updateSelectedCategoryIfNeeded(categoryCell)
        cell = categoryCell

// other cells

    return cell;
}

private func updateSelectedCategoryIfNeeded(cell:CategoryTableViewCell) {
    if let selectedCategory = self.selectedCategory{
        // A category has been selected!
        cell.categoryNameLabel.text = selectedCategory
        updatePicekerRowPosition(cell)
    }else{
        // no category selected!
        cell.categoryNameLabel.text = "Wybierz kategorie..."
    }
}

private func updatePicekerRowPosition(cell:CategoryTableViewCell) {
    if let index = categories.indexOf(selectedCategory!){
        cell.pickerView.selectRow(Int(index.value), inComponent: 0, animated: false)
    }
}
```

**recognizing row selecting**

categoryIndexPath is `private let NSIndexPath`

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    selectedCategory = categories[row]
    if let categoryCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(categoryIndexPath) as? CategoryTableViewCell {
        categoryCell.categoryNameLabel.text = selectedCategory
    }
}
```

Comment: So instead of "Wybierz kategorie" you want there to be the selected category from the picker ? By the way, where is the code that changes the label ? I guess it's in the picker delegate method, can you post that too ?

Comment: @the_critic yes, and I've done it with `pickerView(pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:)` but effect is gone after shrink and correct view shows when this cell is expanded. It's like two  separeted views and they are sync after rebuild by `UITableView`. Maybe video explain it better. https://vid.me/yLSQ . I've also updated my question with `UIPicker` delegate method. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see in your code, there are quite a few things you misunderstand about table views.

I would try to say that more politely, but I can't. **Your way of referencing a categoryCell in your code is completely wrong!** `UITableviewCell`s are not static references if you dequeue them!

**FIRST STEP: Remove the `categoryCell` variable!!!**

The way the table view works is the following:

The `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method takes a cell from the storyboard or your nib and **reuses** that cell over and over again! So, in the beginning, you may get away with doing it your way (creating a reference to `categoryCell`), but the situation changes as soon as you have more cells than fit on the screen, because the variable will reference a different cell!

> Reading recommendation: [Creating and Configuring a Table View](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW10)

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell : UITableViewCell?
    switch(indexPath.row){
  //other cells
    case 1:
        //Kategoria
        let identifier = "category"
        // tableview checks if there is a cached cell 
        // for the identifier (reuse), 
        // if there is, it will take that one!
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier) as! CategoryTableViewCell
        cell.pickerView.delegate = self
        cell.pickerView.dataSource = self
        if let selectedCategory = self.selectedCategory{
            // A category has been selected!
            cell.categoryNameLabel.text = selectedCategory
        }else{
            // no category selected!
            cell.categoryNameLabel.text = "Wybierz kategorie..."
        }
        return cell
  //other cells
}
```

As you can see above, I introduced a new variable called `selectedCategory`, which will reflect which category is currently selected...

Set it up like this in your controller:

```
var selectedCategory : String?
```

What happens when you reload a section or row or the whole table, is that all the `UITableViewDataSource` methods for the given rows are called again! In a way the table view always tries to reflect some state of your model.

You should always reflect changes in your model by reloading the row/section or the whole table (depending on what changed).

So when you pick your category, you change the **model** and reload your row!

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    // update the model!
    selectedCategory = categories[row]

    // the table view now needs to know that the model changed!
    // this will trigger the dataSource method cellForRowAtIndexPath
    // and because it selectedCategory is now set, it will update 
    // your string accordingly!
    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([/*<IndexPath of your categoryLabelCell>*/], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)

}
```

Phew! I hope that helps...

Comment: Thank you I will try with this. I thought approach with cells in variables is better solution becuse I won't have to get same cell from tableView. Also I thought that if tableView cache it then it work in some way.

Comment: I would highly recommend reading the link I posted and related links as well. They help you understand what is really going on... Don't make the mistake and do it willy nilly. It will make you a better programmer, your code more maintainable and your coworkers (or the future-you) will thank you for it. However, I will be here to answer more of your questions if you need my assistance!

Comment: Ok, I did as you say but your solution have one unwanted issue. It's better to show it https://vid.me/KNha I end up with code that I'm putting in edited section. Thanks for your advise it was really helpful. What do you think about my solution?

Comment: @Dudi Did you use the code ? Is your pickerView in the same cell as the label ? If not, you should only reload the cell of the category label that changes. Does that make sense ?

Comment: yes I use the code. Yes pickerView is in the same view as label.

Comment: @Dudi If you reload the whole cell, the pickerview will not preserve its position. You could either set the pickerView's position manually in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` based on the current category, or put it in a separate cell (which I would suggest...).

Comment: Well.. I did something else I explain it in solution section :)